# Calling a method on a Rails object in a .where Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a object Order, each Order has_many line_items (these are television ads).  The LineItem has date as an attribute which is the date that the line_item runs.  To calculate the Order start and end date I use the dates on the line_items.  So I take take the earliest dated line_item and the most recent or furthest into the future line item and those become my start and end dates for the Order.  You can see the methods that calculate the start and end dates below.

```
def start_date
 line_items.first.date rescue nil
end

def end_date
 line_items.last.date rescue nil
end
```

Now I need to be able to get all the orders in the current month.  I am attempting to use a .where query that calls on the start_date and end_date methods within the query.  See the query below.

```
Order.where(start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', Date.today.beginning_of_month, Date.today.end_of_month)
```

I am getting the error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "start_date" does not exist
```

Is it possible to call on a method within a .where query?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to call method in WHERE query.

I can't write working code without your DB schema, but the idea it that you should use JOIN to include line_items records to result set and only then apply condition to line_items fields.